# 'Where' method is not working inside the 'onChange' method

Tags: for-loop, flutter, dart, match

I'm trying to filter data inside a list based on search field input value. I'm running the where method on the list. Since a list has different items on different indexes, therefore I'm running this code in for loop.

Below is an example of the first item in the list;

```dart
print(pageData[0].person);

// ###### OUTPUT ######

Person(id: 2, name: james, nickname: , role: guest, phone: , email: , physical_address: s, created: 2020-02-18 09:12:56.000, updated: 2020-02-18 09:12:56.000)
```

Below I'm trying to find matches using the `where` Method but I'm getting non.

```dart
Widget _buildSearchField() {
    return new TextField(
      controller: new TextEditingController(),
      autofocus: true,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Search...',
        border: InputBorder.none,
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white30),
      ),
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
      onChanged: (val) {
        var i;
        var results = [];

        for (i = 0; i < pageData.length; i++) {
          print('in pageData for loop');
          var matches = pageData[i].where((data) =>
              (data.person.name.toLowerCase().contains('james') ||
                  data.person.nickname.toLowerCase().contains('james')));

/// Code below is not executing

          if (matches != null) {
            print('matches found');
            results.add(matches);
          }
          if (i == pageData.length) {
            setState(() {
              searchResults = results;
            });
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

How do I fix this? What I'm I doing wrong?

Thank you, posted with Love.

Comment: from where are you getting pagedata ?

Comment: It is snapshot.data. `pageData = snapshot.data;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need both the for-loop AND the where-statement.
Try something like this:

```
Widget _buildSearchField() {
return new TextField(
  controller: new TextEditingController(),
  autofocus: true,
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Search...',
    border: InputBorder.none,
    hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white30),
  ),
  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
  onChanged: (val) {
    var i;
    var results = [];

      results = pageData.where((data) =>
       data.person.name.toLowerCase().contains('james') ||
              data.person.nickname.toLowerCase().contains('james');


      );

      setState(() {
        searchResults = results;
      });
    }
  }
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop looks pretty weird to me. Why are you iterating the array like that, and then calling where inside the loop? I had implemented a very similar functionality to what you are trying to achieve in the past, and what I did was something like this:

```dart
        final filtered = testUsers
        .where((user) =>
            user.name.toLowerCase().contains(nameOrNick.toLowerCase()) ||
            user.nick.toLowerCase().contains(nameOrNick.toLowerCase()))
        .toList();
```

I have a `testUsers` `List<User>` that contains a list of `User` objects. I use `where` directly on the list to check if any of the objects have a name or a nick containing the string I am looking for. Then, I create a list from that filtered search, and assign it to a `filtered` variable.

Should work, I don't see any other issue there other than your loop.